# How should I transform code from XHR to Vue-Resource?

Tags: vue.js, xmlhttprequest, vue-resource

I would like to transform the code in `XHR` to `Vue-Resource` request.

XHR:

```
var data = "channel=default";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "url");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.send(data);
```

and here's my code in `Vue-Resource` but I get an error:

```
this.$http.post(
        'url',
        {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
          body: 'channel=default'
        }
      ).then(response => {
          console.log(response.body);
      }, error => {
          console.error(error);
      });
```

I am not sure what's wrong with my `vue` code. I need to pass `channel?default` in body parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `data` as the `second` parameter to the `.post` method.

**It must be in JSON format.**

```
this.$http.post(
    'url',
    { channel: 'default'},
    {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }
).then(response => {
    console.log(response.body);
}, error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: It's not possible yet, I can do it in about 5 more minutes.

Comment: sure, no problem! :)

Comment: and if I wanted to pass some parameters? Would it be corrent to pass an object under `headers` object? `{ data: { property: 'test', id: 1 } }` ?

Comment: What kind of parameters?

Comment: One is a number and the other one is a string, just some data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177563/discussion-between-kabugh-and-julian-paolo-dayag).